# How to enable clustering of RabbitMQ Docker containers

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, message-bus

I have an issue when trying to enable clustering using the official RabbitMQ Docker image - https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/. I'm using `docker-compose` to start my infrastructure, and I cannot get the "slave" nodes to join the cluster. 
When I run `rabbitmqctl cluster_status` on the master, the slaves are not listed.

Here is the output of `rabbitmqctl cluster_status`:

```
$ docker-compose exec master-rabbitmq bash
root@master-rabbitmq:/# rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node 'rabbit@master-rabbitmq' ...
[{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@master-rabbitmq']}]},
 {running_nodes,['rabbit@master-rabbitmq']},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@master-rabbitmq">>},
 {partitions,[]},
 {alarms,[{'rabbit@master-rabbitmq',[]}]}]
```

My `docker-compose.yml` is listed below, for reference.

```
version: "2"
services:
  master-rabbitmq:
      image: rabbitmq:3-management
      hostname: master-rabbitmq
      environment:
        - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=super secret token
      ports:
        - "4369:4369"
        - "5671:5671"
        - "5672:5672"
        - "15671:15671"
        - "15672:15672"
        - "25672:25672"

  slave1-rabbitmq:
      image: rabbitmq:3-management
      hostname: slave1-rabbitmq
      links:
        - "master-rabbitmq:master-rabbitmq"
      environment:
        - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=super secret token

  slave2-rabbitmq:
      image: rabbitmq:3-management
      hostname: slave2-rabbitmq
      links:
        - "master-rabbitmq:master-rabbitmq"
      environment:
        - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=super secret token
```

Comment: Found out why the setup was not working and created a video about it. https://youtu.be/w2kGd2VRJWE

Comment: Have you solved an issue? I have similar one, is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 2):

You will likely have to run

`rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@master-rabbitmq`

On each of the slave nodes

Comment: Thanks a lot! So ignorant of me not to add the video I created after I found the solution: https://youtu.be/w2kGd2VRJWE .

Comment: There's a problem that the containers need to be able to identify each other by host name and so that was also part of why my setup did not work.